# Value object or entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

There is two things in my project Advertiser and BonusPrograms.

Business rules are -:

1. Advertisers will select bonus program from list of bonus programs.
2. Only one bonus program can be assigned at a time, previous bonus program will be discarded for that Advertiser.
3. BonusPrograms are not created by Advertiser, only assigned to them.
4. BonusPrograms are not created per advertiser, it is for all advertisers
5. Any new bonusprogram can be introduced at any time in project

My question are -:

1) I have created Bonus program as a separate agg root against Advertiser root aggregate because , advertiser does not create it, it only assigns it. Do I am correct ?

OR

2) Do i make BonusPrograms as valueobject under Advertiser Aggregate because only one bonusprogram is assigned to Advertiser, When a new one is assigned previous one is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with option 3) which is that BonusProgram is an Entity, but not an Aggregate Root.  It's hard to say w/o knowing more of your domain, but from what you described here, Advertising (or Marketing, or soemthing similar) is the aggregate, and Advertisers and Bonus Programs are entities under that aggregate.  Not sure what the root would be for the aggregate from what you've said, but it doesn't sound like either Advertisers or Bonus Programs to me.

Comment: Advertiser is root aggregate it is sure, but i am confused with bonus programs. Bonusprograms are those things in which advertiser if selected any bonusprogram he had to do some commitment, when that commitment is over , according to that commitment bonus is given. Since Advertiser does not create bonusprogram only assigns to it, so do i put bonus program as seperate root aggregate

Comment: No, as I already said. The aggregate might have many entities, not just the aggregate root.  From what you said about the bonus program, it doesn't sound meaty enough to be its own aggregate to me.

Comment: So tell me, if tomorrow i have to add any new bonusprogram in database, how would i do that without making bonusprgram as root agg, because remember Advertiser does not create bonusprogram it only assign itself to it and advertiser is root entity too.

Comment: With as little of your model as you've shared, it's hard to answer comprehensively.  If you're sure you're not missing a model that's in charge of both Advertisers and BonusPrograms, then you still could have a BonusProgram factory or the like that creates new bonus programs for a advertiser to have assigned to it, and keep the same aggregate root.  I would still argue that there's something in charge of assigning a bonus program to an advertiser, and that "thing" is closer to the aggregate root than the advertiser is.  But a lot of this is judgement, not hard-and-fast

Comment: But i think factory is per root aggregate, here advertiser is root aggregate, moreover he cannot create bonusprogram. My only concern is that if i need a new bonusprogram how would i create them

Comment: A factory is a special kind of service; it might exist outside of an aggregate altogether, and you can have more than one factory per aggregate.  Again, I think the best answer is that you're missing a concept somewhere, but (also again), it's ultimately your decision how you want to model it. There is no "right" answer here.

Comment: No its not true how can an aggregate having more than one factory, how can it maintain invariants with multiple factories

Comment: @Paul Can i have factory method which can create bonusprogram, so that means bonus program is part of advertiser agrregate

Comment: @Kamal, you absolutely can have more than one factory in an aggregate, the aggregate is in charge of synchronising its members, that doesn't mean it does all creating through a single factory.  To do so would violate the Single Responsibility Principle in anything but the simplest of models.  And yes, another option would be a factory method on bonus program itself if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me say I agree with Paul, and you should accept his answer at some point. I'd have made this a comment but I can express my thoughts this way better.

You are asking two questions here, and there are two common sticky concepts in each.

The first question is the notion of where BonusProgram goes with respect to Advertiser if Advertiser is an aggregate root. This is definitely an interesting question, and depends on your domain and use cases. It doesn't depend on whether BP is a value object or entity though, as aggregates will typically contain both. The point of the aggregate is to simplify object traversal for external (to the aggregate root) objects. You accomplish that by picking one root entity that an external object can have a reference to, and only one (for a use case). This means that a client object can have a reference to Advertiser, but not BonusProgram. Advertiser will hold and necessary references to BP in order to satisfy the clinet object's request.

The second question is whether BP is a value object or an entity. Again the answer depends on your domain. The question to always ask yourself is whether you care about the objects identity or not. If you don't care, it is a value object; if you do care it is an entity. The classic case of a value object is Money - while you certainly care about it, you don't typically care about which dollar is which (one dollar is as wonderful as another)! In this case though, BonusProgram smells more like an entity, and you likely are interesting in knowing things like which BP was in effect last month and what were it's results compared to this month's BP.

Again, Paul is saying the same things and you should accept his answer.

HTH,
Berryl